# AppleScript: send terminal process to background and detach

Tags: bash, macos, applescript

After starting a long-running process in `Terminal.app` I want to send the process to the background and then detach it from the terminal so that it doesn't get killed accidentally if the session is closed.

The sequence I am trying to perform is:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.
2. Type `bg` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type `disown` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I converted it to the following AppleScript:

```
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "z" using {control down}
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events" to key code 36
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "bg"
    tell application "System Events" to key code 36
    delay .5
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "disown"
    delay .5
    tell application "System Events" to key code 36
```

The problem is that after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is sent the script does not proceed to the next lines unless I interactively type and then press Enter. What did I miss?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this, but I suggest you install `tmux` or GNU `screen` and use that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works reliably:

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell application process "Terminal"
    activate
    set frontmost to true
    keystroke "z" using {control down}
    keystroke "bg"
    keystroke return
    keystroke "disown"
    keystroke return
  end tell
end tell
```